# C program Sorting Dates

Tags: c

I am doing a C program to sort the dates the user has entered chronologically using the built-in qsort function. I am using structs. My code however does not sort them properly. Any help? Here is the bit of code that I call in my qsort.

```
int comparator(const void *p, const void *q) 
{
    int l3 = ((struct dates *)p)->year;
    int r3 = ((struct dates *)q)->year; 

    if(l3 >= 90 || l3<=99 ){
        if(l3 > r3){
            return 1;   
        }
        else if(l3 < r3){
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else if(l3 > 99){         
        if(l3 > r3){
            return 1;   
        }
        else if(l3 < r3){
            return -1;
        }            
    }   

    int l2 = stringtoInt(((struct dates *)p)->month);
    int r2 = stringtoInt(((struct dates *)q)->month); 

    if (l2 > r2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ( l2 < r2)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    int l = ((struct dates *)p)->day;
    int r = ((struct dates *)q)->day; 

    if (l > r)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if ( l < r)
    {
        return -1;
    }          
}
```

Comment: Your first if construct, "if (l3 >= 90 || l3 <= 99)", will always evaluate to true, so the following else if will never be entered. Everything else looks fine, except I would put an explicit return 0 at the very end of the function.

Comment: @BenFrankel you could write that as an answer.

Comment: `qsort`'s function `comparator` does not return `0` when the dates are the same.

Comment: oh yea
changed it but still sorts them in a really odd way

Comment: @Aleks, what did you change it to?

Comment: @BenFrankel 
l3 >= 90 && l3 <= 99 still odd things goin on

Comment: @Aleks, Well you don't seem to be handling the case where l3 is less than 90, so in that case your comparator will ignore year and move on to comparing the dates by month, then day, which I assume you don't want.

Comment: You have not shown what `struct dates` is, or explained why some of its members are strings, or why you are messing around with the year so much. [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out). Get the data structure right first, so you don't need to fiddle inside what should be a fast and efficient comparator function. Every time it is called, you are making string to integer conversion, goodness knows how many times that is repeated.

Answer (score 3):

Your first if construct,

```
if (l3 >= 90 || l3 <= 99)
```

will always evaluate to true, so the following `else if` will never be entered. I'm assuming the condition is meant to be `l3 >= 90 && l3 <= 99`, although if that's the case, since the following `else if` has the same body, you could merge them into a single if statement, `if (l3 >= 90)`.

Furthermore, you aren't handling the case where `l3 < 90`, so in that case your comparator will ignore year and move on to comparing by month and then day.

I would also add an explicit `return 0` at the end of the function, when the dates are determined to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code seems to be assuming that the year fields are only 2 digits.  It that a valid assumption?

this line:

```
else if(l3 > 99){
```

is not correct, because a 2 digit year 'should' never by greater than 99.

(*I* would suggest using 4 digit years, but such is your data design choice)

However, it seems that if the year is not in the range 90...99 inclusive, then it has to be in the new century

so no need to be checking if the year is > 99, just assume it is in the new century.

What happens when the one-date is in the prior century (90...99) and the other-date is in the next century?  The code does not seem to be accounting for that condition.

Answer (score 0):

**I was working on a schedule maker program so here's the code i have used to sort dates**

```
void LinkedList::appendNode(Node* newNode){
    Node *ptr = head;
    if (head == NULL){
        head = newNode;
    }else{
        //First compare years if newNode year is less than 1st node if yes, interchange them
        if(ptr->year > newNode->year){
            newNode->link = head;
            head = newNode;
        }
        //if years are same then compare months
        else if(ptr->year == newNode->year){

            //compare if newNode month is less than the 1st node in list if yes, interchange them
            if(ptr->month > newNode->month){
                newNode->link = head;
                head = newNode;
            }
            //if months of both are equal compare dates
            else if(ptr->month == newNode->month){

                //compare if date of newNode is smaller than the 1st node. If yes, interchange them
                if(ptr->date > newNode->date){
                    newNode->link = head;
                    head = newNode;
                }
                //if dates are same then, check time
                else if(ptr->date == newNode->date){

                    //compare the hour
                    if(ptr->hour > newNode->hour){
                        newNode->link = head;
                        head = newNode;
                    }
                    //if hour is same check time
                    else if(ptr->hour == newNode->hour){

                        //compare the minute
                        if(ptr->min > newNode->min){
                            newNode->link = head;
                            head = newNode;
                        }
                        else if(ptr->min == newNode->min){
                            newNode->link = head;
                            head = newNode;
                        }
                        //if minute in newNode is greater then traverse and place it accordingly
                        else{
                            ptr = head;

                            //traverse the link till the next node is greater than the newNode
                            while(ptr->link != NULL){
                                if(ptr->link->year > newNode->year)
                                    break;
                                else if(ptr->link->year == newNode->year && ptr->link->month > newNode->month)
                                    break;
                                else if(ptr->link->year == newNode->year && ptr->link->month > newNode->month && ptr->link->date > newNode->date)
                                    break;
                                else if(ptr->link->year==newNode->year&&ptr->link->month>newNode->month&&ptr->link->date==newNode->date&&ptr->link->hour>newNode->hour)
                                    break;
                                else if(ptr->link->year==newNode->year&&ptr->link->month>newNode->month&&ptr->link->date==newNode->date&&ptr->link->hour==newNode->hour&&ptr->link->min>newNode->min)
                                    break;
                                ptr = ptr->link;
                            }
                            newNode->link = ptr->link;
                            ptr->link = newNode;
                        }
                    }

                    //if hour in newNode is greater then traverse and place it accordingly
                    else{
                        ptr = head;
                        //traverse the link till the next node is greater than the newNode
                        while(ptr->link != NULL){
                            if(ptr->link->year > newNode->year)
                                break;
                            else if(ptr->link->year == newNode->year && ptr->link->month > newNode->month)
                                break;
                            else if(ptr->link->year == newNode->year && ptr->link->month > newNode->month && ptr->link->date > newNode->date)
                                break;
                            else if(ptr->link->year==newNode->year&&ptr->link->month>newNode->month&&ptr->link->date==newNode->date&&ptr->link->hour>newNode->hour)
                                break;
                            else if(ptr->link->year==newNode->year&&ptr->link->month>newNode->month&&ptr->link->date==newNode->date&&ptr->link->hour==newNode->hour&&ptr->link->min>newNode->min)
                                break;
                            ptr = ptr->link;
                        }
                        newNode->link = ptr->link;
                        ptr->link = newNode;
                    }
                }
                //else if newNode date is greater
                else{
                    ptr = head;
                    //traverse the link till the next node is greater than the newNode
                    while(ptr->link != NULL){
                        if(ptr->link->year > newNode->year)
                            break;
                        else if(ptr->link->year == newNode->year && ptr->link->month > newNode->month)
                            break;
                        else if(ptr->link->year == newNode->year && ptr->link->month > newNode->month && ptr->link->date > newNode->date)
                            break;
                        ptr = ptr->link;
                    }
                    newNode->link = ptr->link;
                    ptr->link = newNode;
                }
            }
            //else if the month of newNode is greater
            else{
                ptr = head;
                //traverse the link till the next node is greater than the newNode
                while(ptr->link != NULL){
                    if(ptr->link->year > newNode->year)
                        break;
                    else if(ptr->link->year == newNode->year && ptr->link->month > newNode->month)
                        break;
                    else if(ptr->link->year == newNode->year && ptr->link->month > newNode->month && ptr->link->date > newNode->date)
                        break;
                    ptr = ptr->link;
                }
                newNode->link = ptr->link;
                ptr->link = newNode;
            }
        }
        //else if the year of year of newNode is greater
        else{
            ptr = head;
            //traverse the link till the next node is greater than the newNode
            while(ptr->link != NULL){
                if(ptr->link->year > newNode->year)
                    break;
                else if(ptr->link->year == newNode->year && ptr->link->month > newNode->month)
                    break;
                else if(ptr->link->year == newNode->year && ptr->link->month > newNode->month && ptr->link->date > newNode->date)
                    break;
                ptr = ptr->link;
            }
            newNode->link = ptr->link;
            ptr->link = newNode;
        }
    }
}
```